# bulma-calendar not updating as Vue.js component

Tags: vue.js, bulma

I am learning Vue.js and would like to implement the bulma-calendar module in my app. I came this far, but the calendar is somehow not updating, when I am selecting a new Date.

Sorry if I can't specify the problem more, as I said declarative programming is very new to me.

The template I got from the official website of bulma-calendar: https://demo.creativebulma.net/components/calendar/v6//#integration

```js
Vue.component("comp-calendar", {
  template: `
    <div>
        <input ref="calendarTrigger" type="date">
    </div>
    `,

  data: function () {
    return {
      date: new Date(),
    };
  },

  mounted: function () {
    const options = {
      type: "date",
      color: "danger",
      dateFormat: "DD-MM-YYYY",
      startDate: this.date,
      displayMode: "inline",
    };
    const calendar = bulmaCalendar.attach(
      this.$refs.calendarTrigger,
      options
    )[0];
    calendar.on("date:selected", (e) => (this.date = e.date));
  },
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- import bulma -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css">
    <!-- import bulma-calendar -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-calendar@6.0.9/dist/css/bulma-calendar.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <comp-calendar></comp-calendar>
    </div>

    <!-- import bulma-calendar -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-calendar@6.0.9/dist/js/bulma-calendar.min.js"></script>
    <!-- import https://vuejs.org -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js/test.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any help? Thanks

EDIT: Did not help:

```
[...]
<input type="date">
[...]
const calendar = bulmaCalendar.attach('[type="date"]', options)[0];
calendar.on("select", (e) => (this.date = e.date))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a bug in 6.0.9. Working with 6.0.0 (according to documentation here: https://creativebulma.net/product/calendar/demo) worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
calendar.on("select", (e) => (this.date = e.date))
```

here this.date is incorect. this "this" is calendar object not the vue object

Answer (score 0):

This solution work!

```
calendar.on('select', e => (
    
        
    this.date = e.data['datePicker']._date.start))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**